# Wordpress: how to fire a function (myTheme/functions.php) when cron es executed?

Tags: wordpress, cron, hook, action

**I just reformulated this question here:** [Linux + Wordpress: how to fired a function from a Linux Cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344427/linux-wordpress-how-to-fired-a-function-from-a-linux-cron-job)

**Should I close or delete this question?**

---

Just this,how to fire a function (myTheme/functions.php) when cron es executed?

Do I need a hook or action.

I created a real cron job in my Linux server and disabled the Worpress native cron with this `line define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

I will be executed at 00hs every day.

Then, every time the cron is executed I want to execute some taks inside a function.

I read that this function could be useful, but not sure...

```
function fac_all_crons(){
 here my tasks...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cron job, you can include wordpress environment by the following :

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

This will enable you to call any function from your functions.php in your code where you want.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me: 1) where to put this code. 2) how to call it from functions.php (maybe with an example).

Comment: Sorry, I will close this question, I reformulated it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344427/linux-wordpress-how-to-fired-a-function-from-a-linux-cron-job